# Grep includes values that I have not specified

Tags: r

I'm trying to get a list of rows based on some column values, but when I grep for the values, the returned list of rows includes rows with values that I have not specified.

Specifically: I want rows in which `df$likert_classification != NA`, and `df$variable` is 'picture_trained', 'unambig_picture_proportion' or 'ambig_picture_proportion'. But the rows specified by grep includes 'criterion block' rows, which I haven't asked for.

```
url <- 'http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=DbMasR8Y'
df <- read.csv(url, as.is=T)
picture_transfer_trials_likert <- grep('picture_trained|unambig_picture_proportion|ambig_picture_proportion', df$variable[which(!is.na(df$likert_classification))])
unique(df$variable[picture_transfer_trials_likert])
```

`criterion block` should not be included in the rows specified by `picture_transfer_trials_likert`, yet it is. What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you ran into here is that this particular usage of `grep()` returns indexes of matches that apply to *the exact vector that `grep()` received*. You didn't pass `df$variable` to grep, rather, you passed a *subset* of that vector, specifically `df$variable[which(!is.na(df$likert_classification))]`. If you're going to use the resulting indexes to index `df$variable`, you're going to have to subset it in the exact same way for the indexes to be applicable. So for example, this works:

```
unique(df$variable[!is.na(df$likert_classification)][picture_transfer_trials_likert]);
## [1] "unambig_picture_proportion" "picture_trained"            "ambig_picture_proportion"
```

Also notice that I omitted the `which()` call, which is unnecessary here, since you can use logical vector indexing directly, as opposed to numeric vector indexing, which is what you'd be doing with the `which()` call.

But it is also worth mentioning that `grep()` has another very useful mode: You can pass `value=T` to get the actual matches, rather than match indexes, and thus your requirement can be accomplished in one line:

```
unique(grep('^picture_trained$|^unambig_picture_proportion$|^ambig_picture_proportion$', df$variable[!is.na(df$likert_classification)], value=T ));
## [1] "unambig_picture_proportion" "picture_trained"            "ambig_picture_proportion"
```

Also notice that I included anchors in the regex, because it looks to me like you're trying to do an exact full string match. But if that is really the case, then you shouldn't even be using regular expressions, you should be doing string equality testing.

And actually, further to the above, upon looking at your logic, it looks to me like the end result of your code is that you're taking three fixed strings and simply returning whichever of them can be found anywhere in `df$variable` in a row where `df$likert_classification` is not NA. This can actually be done with `intersect()`, passing the vector of fixed strings as the first argument, and the vector of unique values in `df$variable` excluding those in rows with an NA value in `df$likert_classification` as the second argument:

```
intersect(c('picture_trained','unambig_picture_proportion','ambig_picture_proportion'),unique(df$variable[!is.na(df$likert_classification)]));
## [1] "picture_trained"            "unambig_picture_proportion" "ambig_picture_proportion"
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it is to do with how you're filtering the NA observations.  I found that this workaround works... I just changed the `grep` to "picture" as it was faster to type:

```
picture_transfer_trials_likert <- grep('picture', df$variable[df$likert_classification!='NA'])
unique(df$variable[picture_transfer_trials_likert])

#[1] "unambig_picture_proportion" "picture_trained"            "ambig_picture_proportion"
```

This uses your original `grep`:

```
picture_transfer_trials_likert <- grep('picture_trained|unambig_picture_proportion|ambig_picture_proportion', df$variable[df$likert_classification!='NA'])
unique(df$variable[picture_transfer_trials_likert])

#[1] "unambig_picture_proportion" "picture_trained"            "ambig_picture_proportion"
```